# What other options are there to deploy Java Application besides as JAR files?

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment

I am working on a program in Eclipse. I have just finished it and am looking for a way to deploy it. I know that I can use an Export command to deploy a runnable JAR of my program.

I was wondering if there are any other options to deploying my program with Eclipse besides as JAR files? Are there any other ways to deploy the packages of my program and there dependencies into a single directory?

Comment: *"I have just finished it and am looking for a way to deploy it."*  If it has a GUI, the way to deploy it is using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Answer (score 0):

JAR is convenient but not the only way.  If your application fits into a single package then all the class files will fit into a single directory.

Comment: Would I include the produced bin files that are inside the zip folder? I have checked and this is where the java class files are. The only problem is that this directory doesn't include the JAR files I am dependent on. I am curious if their is a utility for Eclipse that parses my packages and existing JARS into a package that I am free to work with?

Answer (score 0):

There are compilers, such as GCJ, which will create native machine code (*.exe files) from Java code.

gcc.gnu.org/java/